# SyntaxError: name "y" is used prior to global variable

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, syntax-error, global-variables

i was writing this code here:

```
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

def ball():
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5)
    global y
    y = y+5
    if y<200:
        canvas.after(100, ball)
```

and i got this -  error name "y" is used  prior to global variable

Comment: `canvas.create_oval(x-5, **y-5**, x+5, **y+5**)`

Comment: The error really says it all. You use  `y` on line 7, and this is *before* the `global y` variable is declared on line 8. You should declare a variable prior to using it

Answer (score 1):

The call to `canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5)` references `y` before you call `global y`. Flip the order and you should be OK:

```py
def ball():
    global y # Could even be done a line later, but it's neater to have it upfront
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5)
    y = y+5
    if y<200:
        canvas.after(100, ball)
```